# Serving Images uploaded to S3 via CloudFront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am uploading images via CarrierWave in my Rails 4 app, to an AWS S3 Bucket. I also have Cloudfront setup, which currently serves up all of my statis assets (Excl. Public uploads).

How do I serve uploaded images via Cloudfront instead of S3, even though they are stored in an S3 Bucket? I have found [tutorials](http://minimul.com/using-s3-and-cloudfront-to-serve-up-images.html) like this, but since I already have a CloudFront distribution running, I was wondering if I should add another one for my Public Image uploads or is there a way to add it to my Current distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the bucket as an additional custom origin to your existing Cloudfront distribution.

You can then use path patterns to determine which prefixes (e.g. `/images/uploads/*`) should route to the alternate origin.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern

Since creating distributions doesn't cost anything except a few minutes of your time while you wait for the distribution to become globally available, I'd suggest creating a new distribution for experimentation before adding this to your production distribution... but this is definitely doable.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. This solution was not difficult to implement. But for some reason when I load my app, the Images in /uploads/* is still routed from S3 and not cloudfront (As per page source code). I have given it quite a while as well and made sure that the update has been completed.

Comment: @Herm that sounds like an issue with either your app configuration... or old copies of your pages, with old links, are still being served from the Cloudfront cache.

Comment: Might this perhaps have something to do with my bucket policy? Is there something that I need to change in my Policy?